# How to change array keys according the it's elements

Tags: php, arrays

I need to change array value based on specific value. Take a look at this array below :

```
Array
( 
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [title] => 
            [nomor] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [title] => 
            [nomor] => 2
        )

)
```

I need to change the array key based on `nomor` value. How can I do that?

Comment: change array key by it's own value? It's look like you want to change key with there own value. better to add your expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_column` for that ([doc)](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) as:

```
$arr = array_column($arr, null, "nomor");
```

[Live example](https://3v4l.org/tRR9MA)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply create a new array, loop through your existing one, and save each elements into the new one with the proper key.

```
foreach($array as $element) {
    $formatted_array[$element['nomor']] = $element;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle:
https://3v4l.org/PlbJ1

**Edit:** Keep in mind though, if multiple elements have the same value as "nomor", the latest will override the previous one.

**Edit 2:** Per the other answer, PHP's array_column function seems to do this simpler.

Comment: This answer will work - but this can done with PHP build-in function which I think better practice

Comment: Yes, your solution is better, I updated. I wasn't aware of array_column. PHP seems to have lots of obscure array functions that I haven't actually seen in action before.